# Query not being added to SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get

Query not being run on SQL Database using PHP. The output says so, but when I check for it, it isn't there. Please help! Btw 'connectdb.php' connects to sql and the database. Is there a function I'm forgetting or something?

```
<?php
$userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["UserId"]);
$banner = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["banner"]);
include "connectdb.php";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banned WHERE Userid='$userId'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if (numrows == 1) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot $ in your if condition maybe that is why your code is not working

```
<?php

include "connectdb.php";

$userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["UserId"]);
$banner = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["banner"]);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banned WHERE Userid='$userId'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 1) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

If there is a column in the `banned` table with `Userid` field as `$userId`, the above code would return `true` else it would return `false`.

Comment: are you getting a value in UserId?

Comment: Yes this is the output: "UserId: 232 banned by Usering"

Comment: this should echo true if $userId exists in your "banned" table

Comment: Why would you remove the escape calls and make the query vulnerable to SQL injection attacks?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question directly:

You should while debugging, add the following to your query lines as follows, to get an output of the error:

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

That point aside, consider using PDO, you will find it's error messages are very verbose and also will save you from having to run the mysql_real_escape_string(), and provide more protection from SQL injection.

Comment: I added the cash mark to numrows in the if statement and added the mysql query. Still doesn't add to it.

Comment: What is the output if you run this?  Do you have error display turned on?$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banned WHERE Userid='$userId'")or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a $ before numrows in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

place your include link at the top of the file

```
include "connectdb.php";
$userId = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["UserId"]);
$banner = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["banner"]);
```

And then add a $ to numrows

```
if ($numrows == 1) {
```

your can also use

```
if ($numrows > 0) {
```